# Replace PDF string

Tags: python, pdf

Task: I need to replace any string in pdf file.
Now i'm use this code:

```
import os
import argparse
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import DecodedStreamObject, EncodedStreamObject


def replace_text(content, replacements = dict()):
    lines = content.splitlines()

    result = ""
    in_text = False

    for line in lines:
        if line == "BT":
            in_text = True

        elif line == "ET":
            in_text = False

        elif in_text:
            cmd = line[-2:]
            if cmd.lower() == 'tj':
                replaced_line = line
                for k, v in replacements.items():
                    replaced_line = replaced_line.replace(k, v)
                result += replaced_line + "\n"
            else:
                result += line + "\n"
            continue

        result += line + "\n"

    return result


def process_data(object, replacements):
    data = object.get_data()
    decoded_data = data.decode('utf-8')
    print(decoded_data)

    replaced_data = replace_text(decoded_data, replacements)

    encoded_data = replaced_data.encode('utf-8')
    if object.decoded_self is not None:
        object.decoded_self.set_data(encoded_data)
    else:
        object.set_data(encoded_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-i", "--input", required=True, help="path to PDF document")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())

    in_file = args["input"]
    filename_base = in_file.replace(os.path.splitext(in_file)[1], "")

    # Provide replacements list that you need here
    replacements = { 'test': 'testReplace'}

    pdf = PdfReader(in_file)
    writer = PdfWriter()

    for page_number in range(0, len(pdf.pages)):

        page = pdf.pages[page_number]
        contents = page.get_contents()

        if isinstance(contents, DecodedStreamObject) or isinstance(contents, EncodedStreamObject):
            process_data(contents, replacements)
        elif len(contents) > 0:
            for obj in contents:
                if isinstance(obj, DecodedStreamObject) or isinstance(obj, EncodedStreamObject):
                    streamObj = obj.getObject()
                    process_data(streamObj, replacements)

        writer.add_page(page)

    with open(filename_base + ".result.pdf", 'wb') as out_file:
        writer.write(out_file)
```

If you see i'm use print(decoded_data). So with simple pdf i receive this:

```
2 J
BT
0 0 0 rg
/F1 0027 Tf
57.3750 722.2800 Td
( A Simple PDF File ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 688.6080 Td
( This is a small demonstration .pdf file - ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 664.7040 Td
( just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 652.7520 Td
( text. And more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 628.8480 Td
( And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 616.8960 Td
( text. And more text. Boring, zzzzz. And more text. And more text. And ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 604.9440 Td
( more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 592.9920 Td
( And more text. And more text. ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 569.0880 Td
( And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 557.1360 Td
( text. And more text. And more text. Even more. Continued on page 2 ...) Tj
ET

2 J
BT
0 0 0 rg
/F1 0027 Tf
57.3750 722.2800 Td
( Simple PDF File 2 ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 688.6080 Td
( ...continued from page 1. Yet more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 676.6560 Td
( And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 664.7040 Td
( text. Oh, how boring typing this stuff. But not as boring as watching ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 652.7520 Td
( paint dry. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj
ET
BT
/F1 0010 Tf
69.2500 640.8000 Td
( Boring.  More, a little more text. The end, and just as well. ) Tj
ET
```

But with different pdf that actually i need to change it's output this:

```
/Artifact <</Attached [/Top /Bottom /Left /Right ]/BBox [0 0 540 780 ]/Type /Background >>BDC
q
0 0 540 780 re
W n
q
1 0 0 -1 0 0 cm
BX /Sh0 sh EX Q
EMC
/Figure <</MCID 2 >>BDC
Q
q
222.6 641.64 94.8 27.84 re
W* n
q
100 0 0 33 220 639 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
EMC
Q
BT
/P <</MCID 4 >>BDC
/CS1 cs 1  scn
/TT0 1 Tf
18 0 0 18 250.0174 441.8232 Tm
[(CA)-1.3(T)]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 6 >>BDC
-0.001 Tc -0.001 Tw -2.613 -2.4 Td
[(T)-4(ra)-1.7(d)-1(i)-3.7(ng R)1(e)2(p)-1(o)-2(rt)]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 9 >>BDC
/TT1 1 Tf
0.004 Tc -0.004 Tw 11.04 0 0 11.04 256.4348 56.0341 Tm
[(2)-0.6(0)8.2(2)-0.6(3)]TJ
EMC
ET

/Artifact <</Attached [/Top /Bottom /Left /Right ]/BBox [0 0 540 780 ]/Type /Background >>BDC
/CS0 cs 1  scn
0 0 540 780 re
f
EMC
/Figure <</MCID 2 >>BDC
q
237.72 710.64 64.56 19.08 re
W* n
q
70 0 0 24 235 708 cm
/Im0 Do
Q
EMC
Q
BT
/P <</MCID 4 >>BDC
/CS1 cs 0.118 0.122 0.129  scn
/TT0 1 Tf
-0.007 Tc -0.001 Tw 8.04 0 0 8.04 49.9377 587.5112 Tm
[(Th)-1.6(e )-29.6(a)-14(v)-2.4(er)-9(a)-14(g)-7.6(e )-14.6(n)-1.7(u)-5.6(m)-5.7(b)-0.7(er)-9( )-14.7(o)-6.8(f)-11.3( d)-0.6(a)-14(i)-6.7(l)-6.7(y)-2.3( t)-4(r)-9(a)-14(d)-0.7(es)-10.5(:)-4( )]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 7 >>BDC
/TT1 1 Tf
0.005 Tc -0.012 Tw -0.207 5.605 Td
[(H)9(er)7.1(e ar)7.1(e )-14.6(t)11.1(h)3.4(e ac)3.9(h)3.4(i)10.5(ev)0.9(em)13.2(en)3.5(t)11.1(s)12.5( w)-1.4(e )30.2(r)7.1(eac)3.9(h)3.5(ed)5.4( )15.3(f)0.9(r)7.1(o)8.2(m)-1.7( )]TJ
/C2_0 1 Tf
0 Tc 0 Tw 0 -1.194 TD
[<0640>3.7<050C>-4.5<0506051F>6.6<05060641>4.7<0003>7.3<0248>6.1<020C>3.2<0003>-7.6<0640>3.8<050C>-4.6<0506051F>6.5<05060641>4.7<0628>]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 10 >>BDC
14.04 0 0 14.04 205.4003 586.4577 Tm
<048304830483>Tj
EMC
ET
/Figure <</MCID 12 >>BDC
q
48.3 616.53 m
233.958 616.53 l
233.958 615.03 l
48.3 615.03 l
h
W n
q
0 g
1 0 0 -1 96.5999985 0 cm
BX /Sh0 sh EX Q
EMC
Q
BT
/P <</MCID 14 >>BDC
/TT0 1 Tf
8.04 0 0 8.04 291.8126 595.0192 Tm
(-)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 16 >>BDC
T*
(-)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 18 >>BDC
T*
(-)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 20 >>BDC
T*
(-)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 22 >>BDC
T*
(-)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 24 >>BDC
T*
(-)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 26 >>BDC
T*
(-)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 28 >>BDC
T*
(-)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 30 >>BDC
T*
(-)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 32 >>BDC
T*
(-)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 35 >>BDC
/TT1 1 Tf
-0.005 Tc -0.017 Tw -0.045 15.416 Td
[(Th)-6.6(e)-9.8( )-29.7(m)-11.6(o)-1.8(s)-12.4(t)1( s)-12.4(u)-10.5(c)-6.1(c)-6.1(e)-9.9(s)-12.4(s)2.5(f)-9.1(u)-10.6(l )15.2(p)-5.6(a)-9.9(ir)-2.9(s)-12.4( id)-4.6(e)-9.9(n)-6.5(t)1.1(if)-9.2(ie)-9.8(d)-4.6( b)-5.6(y)-9.1( )-14.7(u)-10.5(s)-12.4( )-14.7(o)-1.8(v)-9.1(e)-9.8(r)-3( )]TJ
-0.006 Tc -0.001 Tw T*
[(th)-7.6(e)-10.8( m)-12.7(o)-2.8(n)-7.5(th)]TJ
/C2_0 1 Tf
0.005 Tc -0.005 Tw 5.746 0 Td
[<0640>8.7<051C050D051D>9.4<050D0524>-0.8<050D051A>5.4<0529>11.9<0641>]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 38 >>BDC
/TT1 1 Tf
-0.003 Tc 0.011 Tw -16.424 -36.296 Td
[(G)-7.1(r)-1(ow)-9.4(t)3.1(h)-4.6( )30.2(of)-7.2( )15.3(t)3.1(h)-4.5(e)-7.9( C)-7.3(AT)2( c)-4.1(om)-9.7(m)-9.7(u)-8.6(n)-4.6(i)17.4(t)3(y)-7.1( )]TJ
EMC
ET
/Figure <</MCID 40 >>BDC
q
206.46 328.65 m
330.06 328.65 l
330.06 327.15 l
206.46 327.15 l
h
W n
q
0 g
1 0 0 -1 412.9199829 0 cm
BX /Sh1 sh EX Q
EMC
Q
BT
/P <</MCID 42 >>BDC
/TT0 1 Tf
-0.007 Tc -0.001 Tw 8.04 0 0 8.04 49.9377 432.287 Tm
[(Th)-1.6(es)-10.6(e )-29.6(f)-11.3(i)-6.6(g)-7.6(u)-5.6(r)-9(es)-10.6( r)-9(ep)-0.7(r)-9(es)-10.5(en)-1.6(t)-4( )-14.7(o)-6.8(u)-5.7(r)-9( p)-0.7(er)-9(f)-11.3(o)-6.8(r)-9(m)-5.7(a)-14(n)-1.7(c)-11.1(e )-14.6(d)-0.7(u)-5.6(r)-9(i)-6.7(n)-1.6(g)-7.6( )]TJ
0.004 Tc -0.012 Tw T*
[(t)7(h)9.4(e)11( )-14.7(s)0.5(p)10.3(e)11(ci)4.4(fi)4.3(e)11(d)10.4( p)10.4(e)11(r)2(i)4.3(o)4.2(d)10.3( a)-3(n)9.3(d)10.4( sh)9.4(o)4.1(w)2.4(ca)-3.1(s)0.5(e)11( )30.1(t)7(h)9.4(e)11( )-14.7(r)2(e)11(s)0.5(u)5.3(l)4.3(t)7.1(s )]TJ
-0.005 Tc -0.003 Tw T*
[(w)-6.6(e)2( )-14.7(ha)-12.1(ve)2( )-14.7(a)-12(t)-2(t)-2(a)-12(i)-4.6(ne)2(d)1.3( i)-4.7(n t)-1.9(e)1.9(r)-6.9(m)-3.8(s)-8.5( )-14.7(o)-4.8(f)-9.3( t)-1.9(r)-7(a)-12.1(d)1.4(i)-4.7(ng)-5.6( a)-12.1(c)-9.1(t)-2(i)-4.7(vi)-4.6(t)-2.1(y,)-1.9( )]TJ
0 Tc -0.023 Tw T*
[(p)6.4(r)-2(of)-4.3(it)3(a)-7(b)6.3(ilit)3(y)4.7(,)3( )-14.7(a)-7(n)5.3(d)6.4( m)1.3(a)-7(r)-2(k)4(e)6.9(t)3.1( )-29.7(op)6.3(p)6.4(or)-2(t)3(u)1.4(n)5.3(it)3(ie)7(s)-3.5(.)]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 45 >>BDC
/C2_1 1 Tf
0 Tw 0 19.611 TD
[<00C0>6.8<020C0248>3<018A>-7<01F60003>8.3<022F>6.3<0232>-1.9<020C01CF>-4.3<01DE0248>3<0003>8.2<01A6>6.4<026F>4.7<0003>-6.7<0640>0.7<022F>6.3<01B5>7<0232>-2<01DE020C01AE>6.4<0634>6.6<01FF>1.3<020C0201>5.4<0248>3<01D8>5.4<0641>0.6<0628>]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 48 >>BDC
/C2_0 1 Tf
14.04 0 0 14.04 205.4003 560.1061 Tm
<048304830483>Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 51 >>BDC
/TT0 1 Tf
-0.007 Tc 0.014 Tw 8.04 0 0 8.04 49.9377 536.4824 Tm
[(Hi)-6.6(g)-7.6(h)-1.7(es)-10.5(t)-4( )15.3(t)-4(r)-9(a)-14(d)-0.7(e s)-10.6(p)-0.6(r)-9(ea)-14.1(d)-0.6(:)-3.9( \()]TJ
EMC
/Span <</MCID 52 >>BDC
/C2_1 1 Tf
-0.006 Tc 0.006 Tw 11.358 0 Td
[<051C>-3.6<051D>-6.6<051B>-11.8<0525>-8.6<050D051A>-2.6<051F>-10.6<0641>]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 56 >>BDC
/C2_0 1 Tf
0 Tc 0 Tw 14.04 0 0 14.04 205.4003 535.429 Tm
<048304830483>Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 59 >>BDC
/TT0 1 Tf
-0.007 Tc -0.001 Tw 8.04 0 0 8.04 49.9377 509.5699 Tm
[(Th)-1.6(e )-29.6(n)-1.7(u)-5.6(m)-5.7(b)-0.7(er)-9( o)-6.9(f)-11.3( )-14.6(i)-6.7(n)-1.6(t)-4(er)-8.9(ex)-10.3(c)-11.1(h)-1.7(a)-14(n)-1.7(g)-7.5(e )]TJ
-0.005 Tc 0.005 Tw 0 -1.194 TD
[(t)-2(r)-7(a)-12(ns)-8.6(a)-12(c)-9.2(t)-2(i)-4.6(o)-4.9(ns)6.3(:)]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 62 >>BDC
/C2_0 1 Tf
0 Tc 0 Tw 14.04 0 0 14.04 205.4003 500.8541 Tm
<048304830483>Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 65 >>BDC
/TT0 1 Tf
-0.007 Tc -0.001 Tw 8.04 0 0 8.04 49.9377 477.187 Tm
[(Th)-1.6(e )-29.6(n)-1.7(u)-5.6(m)-5.7(b)-0.7(er)-9( o)-6.9(f)-11.3( )-14.6(t)-4(r)-9(a)-14(d)-0.7(es)-10.6( i)-6.6(n)-1.7( c)-11.2(r)-9(y)-2.3(p)-0.7(t)-3.9(o)-6.9( )]TJ
0.002 Tc -0.002 Tw T*
[(a)-5(rb)8.4(i)2.3(t)5(ra)-5(g)1.4(e)9(:)]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 68 >>BDC
/C2_0 1 Tf
0 Tc 0 Tw 14.04 0 0 14.04 205.4003 468.1051 Tm
<048304830483>Tj
EMC
ET
/Figure <</MCID 70 >>BDC
q
290.82 616.53 m
476.478 616.53 l
476.478 615.03 l
290.82 615.03 l
h
W n
q
0 g
1 0 0 -1 581.6400146 0 cm
BX /Sh2 sh EX Q
EMC
Q
BT
/P <</MCID 72 >>BDC
/TT0 1 Tf
-0.008 Tw 8.04 0 0 8.04 107.1524 300.7571 Tm
[(W)6.5(e)7( )-14.7(a)-7(r)-1.9(e)6.9( )-14.6(d)6.4(e)6.9(liv)4.7(e)7(r)-2(in)5.3(g)-0.6( )-14.6(r)-2(e)7(s)-3.5(u)1.3(lt)3.1(s)-3.6( f)-4.3(a)-7(s)-3.5(t)3(e)7(r)-2( t)3.1(h)5.3(a)-7(n)5.4( a)-7.1(n)5.4(t)3(ic)-4.2(ip)6.4(a)-7(t)3(e)7(d)6.3( )15.2(a)-7(n)5.4(d)6.3( n)5.4(ot)3( s)-3.6(low)-1.6(in)5.3(g)-0.6( )30.2(d)6.3(ow)-1.6(n)5.3(!)6.3( T)6.8(h)5.4(e)6.9( )-29.5(C)2.6(A)0.5(T)6.9( )]TJ
-1.761 -1.194 Td
[(c)-4.2(om)1.3(m)1.3(u)1.3(n)5.4(it)3(y)4.7( )15.2(h)5.4(a)-7(s)-3.6( e)7(x)-3.3(p)6.3(e)7(r)-2(ie)7(n)5.3(c)-4.1(e)6.9(d)6.4( )-14.6(s)-3.6(ig)-0.6(n)5.3(if)-4.3(ic)-4.1(a)-7(n)5.3(t)3( )30.2(g)-0.6(r)-2(ow)-1.6(t)3(h)5.3(,)3.1( n)5.4(ot)3( on)5.3(ly)4.6( in)5.3( )-14.6(t)3(h)5.3(e)7( )-14.6(liq)6.3(u)1.4(id)6.4(it)3(y)4.7( )15.2(p)6.4(r)-2(ov)4.7(id)6.3(e)7(d)6.4( )-14.7(t)3(o t)3.1(h)5.3(e)7( )]TJ
0.149 -1.194 Td
[(C)2.6(A)0.6(T)6.8( )-14.7(t)3.1(r)-2(a)-7(d)6.3(in)5.3(g)-0.6( t)3(e)7(a)-7(m)1.3( b)6.3(u)1.4(t)3( )-14.6(a)-7.1(ls)-3.5(o )15.2(in)5.4( t)3(h)5.3(e)7( )-14.6(p)6.3(r)-2(of)-4.3(it)3(a)-7(b)6.4(ilit)3(y)4.7( )15.2(e)7(n)5.4(j)5.3(oy)4.6(e)7(d)6.4( )-44.5(b)6.3(y)4.7( )-14.6(ou)1.3(r)-1.9( c)-4.2(lie)6.9(n)5.4(t)3(s)-3.5(.)3( T)6.8(h)5.4(is)-3.5( e)7(x)-3.3(p)6.3(a)-7(n)5.3(s)-3.5(ion)5.3( )30.2(h)5.3(a)-7(s)-3.5( )]TJ
-0.007 Tc 0.014 Tw 0.866 -1.194 Td
[(b)-0.6(een)-1.6( )-14.6(m)-5.7(a)-14(d)-0.7(e )15.3(p)-0.7(o)-6.8(s)-10.6(s)-10.5(i)-6.7(b)-0.6(l)-6.7(e )30.2(b)-0.7(y)-2.3( t)-4(h)-1.7(e C)-4.5(A)-6.4(T m)-5.7(a)-14(r)-9(k)-3(et)-3.9(i)-6.7(n)-1.6(g)-7.6( )15.3(t)-4(ea)-14(m)-5.7( a)-14(n)-1.7(d)-0.6( )30.2(t)-4(h)-1.7(e )-14.6(C)-4.4(A)-6.4(T B)-14.2(o)-6.9(n)-1.6(u)-5.7(s)-10.5( )45.1(s)-10.6(y)-2.3(s)-10.5(t)-4(em)-5.7(,)-4( w)-8.6(h)-1.7(er)-9(e )]TJ
-0.005 Tc -0.003 Tw -1.269 -1.194 Td
[(t)-2(ho)-4.9(s)-8.6(e)2( w)-6.6(ho)-4.8( s)-8.5(ha)-12(r)-7(e)2( t)-2(he)2( )-14.6(b)1.3(e)2(ne)2(f)-9.3(i)-4.6(t)-2(s)-8.6( o)-4.9(f)-9.3( )-14.6(C)-2.5(A)-4.4(T)1.9( )-14.7(w)-6.6(i)-4.7(t)-2(h t)-1.9(he)2(i)-4.7(r)-7( )-14.6(f)-9.3(r)-7(i)-4.7(e)2(nd)1.3(s)-8.5( )15.1(c)-9.1(a)-12(n i)-4.7(nc)-9.2(r)-7(e)2(a)-12(s)-8.6(e)2( t)-2(he)2(i)-4.7(r)-6.9( )-14.7(e)2(a)-12.1(r)-6.9(ni)-4.6(ng)-5.6(s)-8.5(,)-2( w)-6.6(hi)-4.6(c)-9.2(h )]TJ
5.209 -1.194 Td
[(c)-9.2(a)-12(n b)1.4(e)1.9( )-14.6(w)-6.6(i)-4.7(t)-2(hd)1.3(r)-6.9(a)-12.1(w)-6.6(n )30.1(a)-12(s)-8.6( )15.2(p)1.4(r)-7(o)-4.9(f)-9.3(i)-4.6(t)-2(s)-8.6( o)-4.9(r)-7( r)-7(e)2(i)-4.7(nve)2(s)-8.5(t)-2(e)2(d)1.3( )-29.6(t)-2(o)-4.8( e)2(nha)-12(nc)-9.2(e)2( )-14.7(d)1.3(a)-12(i)-4.6(l)-4.7(y r)-7(e)2(w)-6.6(a)-12(r)-7(d)1.4(s)-8.6(.)]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 75 >>BDC
/TT1 1 Tf
0.002 Tc -0.002 Tw 24 0 0 24 176.3672 202.8556 Tm
(XXX)Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 78 >>BDC
/TT0 1 Tf
-0.007 Tc -0.016 Tw 8.04 0 0 8.04 160.0067 190.3461 Tm
[(C)-4.4(A)-6.4(T )-29.7(p)-0.6(l)-6.7(a)-14(t)-4(f)-11.3(o)-6.8(r)-9(m)-5.7( r)-8.9(ec)-11.1(ei)-6.6(v)-2.3(ed)-0.7( )]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 81 >>BDC
/C2_0 1 Tf
-0.002 Tc 0.002 Tw 24 0 0 24 309.4273 202.8556 Tm
<048304830483>Tj
EMC
/P <</MCID 84 >>BDC
/TT0 1 Tf
0 Tc -0.008 Tw 8.04 0 0 8.04 279.0002 190.3461 Tm
[(%)-6.8( of)-4.3( t)3(h)5.3(e)7( )-14.6(t)3(ot)3(a)-7(l c)-4.1(a)-7(p)6.3(it)3(a)-7(l )15.2(u)1.4(t)3(iliz)3.5(e)7(d)6.4(  )]TJ
EMC
/P <</MCID 87 >>BDC
/C2_1 1 Tf
-0.006 Tc 0.013 Tw -22.598 -5.425 Td
[<0058>-2.5<0201>-0.6<0003>2.2<0640>-5.3<0519>-7.1<050D051E>-10.2<0536>-11.9<0525>-8.6<0641>-5.3<0629>-3<0003>-12.6<0248>-3<01D8>-0.6<01B5>0.9<0003>-12.6<0021>-3.4<0004>-5.4<00C0>0.8<0003>-12.7<022F01F6>-5.7<018A>-13<0248>-2.9<01CF>-10.3<020C>-5.9<0232>-8<01FF>-4.7<0003>2.3<0232>-8<01B5>1<01A7>-10.1<01B5>0.9<01DE>-5.6<0268>-1.3<01B5>1<01AE0003>-27.6<0640>-5.3<051E>-10.2<05200519>-7<0519>-7.1<0506>-5.1<0641>-5.3<0003>2.2<0020>-13.1<0079>1<0020>-13.2<0629>-3<0003>2.3<0269>-7.6<01DE>-5.6<0248>-3<01D8>-0.7<0003>17.2<0248>-2.9<01D8>-0.7<01B5>1<0003>-12.6<01F6>-5.7<01DE>-5.6<02310250>-4.6<01DE>-5.7<01AE01DE>-5.7<0248>-2.9<026F>-1.4<0003>2.3<022F0232>-8<020C>-5.9<0268>-1.3<01DE>-5.6<01AE01B5>1<01AE0003>-12.7<01A6026F>-1.3<0003>2.3<0248>-3<01D8>-0.7<01B5>1<0003>]TJ
0 Tc 0 Tw -0.776 -1.194 Td
[<0021>2.6<0004>0.6<00C0>6.8<0003>-6.7<01A7>-4.1<020C01FF>1.3<01FF>1.3<0250>1.4<0201>5.3<01DE0248>3<026F>4.7<0003>23.2<018A>-7<01A7>-4.2<01A7>-4.2<020C0250>1.4<0201>5.4<0248>3<01DE0201>5.4<01D0>-0.6<0003>38.1<01CF>-4.2<020C0232>-2<0003>-6.7<0640>0.7<051C>2.3<051D051B>-5.8<0525>-2.6<050D>6.1<051A>3.3<051F>-4.6<0641>0.7<0003>23.2<020C01CF>-4.3<0003>8.3<0248>3<01D8>5.4<01B5>6.9<0003>-21.5<0248>3<020C0248>3<018A>-7<01F60003>23.2<01A7>-4.2<018A>-7<022F>6.3<01DE0248>3<018A>-7<01F60003>23.2<0250>1.4<0248>3<01DE01F601DE0279>3.5<01B5>7<01AE>6.4<0003>-6.7<01DE0201>5.3<0003>8.3<01A7>-4.2<0232>-2<026F>4.7<022F>6.4<0248>3<020C0003>8.2<018A>-7<0232>-2<01A6>6.4<01DE0248>3<0232>-1.9<018A>-7.1<01D001B5>7<062E>3<0003>]TJ
0.007 Tw 0.896 -1.194 Td
[<00B2>3<01DE01FF>1.3<01DE01F6018A>-7<0232>-2<01F6026F>4.7<0629>3.1<0003>8.2<0248>3<01D8>5.4<01B5>7<0003>-6.7<0021>2.6<0004>0.6<00C0>6.8<0003>-6.6<01A7>-4.2<020C01FF>1.3<01FF>1.3<0250>1.4<0201>5.4<01DE0248>3<026F>4.7<0003>23.2<0269>-1.6<01DE0248>3.1<01D8>5.3<01AE>6.4<0232>-2<01B5>7<0269>-1.6<0003>8.2<0640>0.7<051E>-4.2<0520>5.8<0519>-1.1<0519>-1<0506>0.9<0641>0.7<0003>8.2<0020>-7.2<0079>7<0020>-7.1<0003>23.1<01CF>-4.2<0232>-2<020C01FF>1.3<0003>8.3<0248>3<01D8>5.3<01B5>7<0003>-6.6<022F>6.3<01F6018A>-7<0248>3<01CF>-4.3<020C0232>-2<01FF>1.4<0629>3<0003>8.3<0250>1.3<0248>3<01DE01F601DE0279>3.5<01DE0201>5.3<01D0>-0.6<0003>8.3<0248>3<01D8>5.4<01B5>7<0003>]TJ
/TT0 1 Tf
-0.007 Tc 0.014 Tw -0.507 -1.194 Td
[(ea)-14(r)-9(n)-1.7(ed)-0.6( f)-11.3(u)-5.6(n)-1.7(d)-0.6(s)-10.6( )30.2(t)-4(o)-6.8( a)-14(c)-11.2(h)-1.6(i)-6.7(ev)-2.3(e t)-4(h)-1.6(ei)-6.7(r)-9( g)-7.6(o)-6.9(a)-14(l)-6.7(s)-10.5(.)-3.9( )30.2(Wi)-6.7(t)-4(h)-1.6( r)-9(ec)-11.2(en)-1.6(t)-4( c)-11.1(o)-6.9(n)-1.6(t)-4(es)-10.6(t)-4(s)-10.5(,)-4( )15.3(a)-14(c)-11.2(t)-4(i)-6.7(v)-2.3(i)-6.6(t)-4(i)-6.7(es)-10.5(,)-4( )15.3(a)-14(n)-1.7(d)-0.6( )15.2(r)-8.9(ep)-0.6(r)-9(es)-10.5(en)-1.6(t)-4(a)-14(t)-4(i)-6.7(v)-2.3(e )]TJ
0 Tc -0.008 Tw 0.881 -1.194 Td
[(b)6.4(r)-2(oa)-7(d)6.4(c)-4.2(a)-7(s)-3.6(t)3(s)-3.5(,)3.1( )30.1(t)3(h)5.3(e)7( )-14.6(C)2.6(A)0.6(T)6.8( )-14.7(c)-4.1(om)1.3(m)1.3(u)1.4(n)5.3(it)3(y)4.7( is)-3.6( )15.2(p)6.4(ois)-3.6(e)7(d)6.4( f)-4.3(or)-2( e)7(v)4.7(e)6.9(n)5.4( )-44.5(g)-0.6(r)-1.9(e)6.9(a)-7(t)3(e)7(r)-2( )-14.6(g)-0.6(r)-2(ow)-1.6(t)3(h)5.3( in)5.3( t)3(h)5.4(e)6.9( )-14.6(n)5.3(u)1.4(m)1.3(b)6.4(e)6.9(r)-1.9( )-14.7(of)-4.3( )]TJ
-0.006 Tc 0.006 Tw 17.642 -1.194 Td
[(pa)-13.1(r)-7.9(t)-3(i)-5.7(c)-10.1(i)-5.7(pa)-13(n)-0.7(t)-2.9(s)-9.6(.)]TJ
EMC
ET
```

What is wrong? Why in first case i had received strings with text but in second case i had received this incomprehensible data?

Comment: If something looks like a text in PDF it may not be text actually.

Comment: hmm... Okay, but when i'm edit this pdf in pdf-editor i can change strings like simple text...
Maybe it's behavior of some format?

Comment: Please consider reading the pdf specification. You'll see that up till now you have only considered very simplistic special cases.

Comment: @SergeySamokhvalov I am pretty sure that your editor has much more advanced parsing and editting capabilities that handle all cases and ways of text encoding. That's why those programs often cost money.